# How do I convert a data set to an array

Tags: powershell

After pulling data from SQL in powershell, I have a dataset.
How do I convert this to an array?

`$data.tables | gm` gives me `TypeName: System.Data.DataSet`

If I ask for information from the table I pulled, I get:

```
$data.Tables | fl

ServerName              : Server10
SamAccount              : Admin-Server10
```

but $data is read only.  I don't plan on writing back to the database, but want to be able to work with and change the data while in memory.

What I want is a string array that holds these values.

Sure, I could do:

`$x = "" | select servername,SamAccount
$x.Servername = $data.tables.servername`

but there has to be an easier way.  The dataset I've pulled has over 100 columns.

Is there a way to convert this to just a string array (or whatever it's called)..  A string where I can access the data elements within it?

What I want to be able to is use:

`write-host "$($x.servername)"`

and get Server10

BTW, there is only 1 row of data in the dataset..  Just lots of columns.

Comment: Sounds like the single row is why it’s not an array to begin with. Because it’s not. If you get your dataset into a Powershell ‘object’ (variable) and do $data[0] what does it return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an object for each row, and then populate their values based off the table's columns. That would give you a PSCustomObject for each row with properties that you can reference and modify.

```
    $MyArray = ForEach($Row in $Data.Tables[0].Rows){
    $Record = New-Object PSObject
    ForEach($Col in $Data.Tables[0].Columns.ColumnName){
        Add-Member -InputObject $Record -NotePropertyName $Col -NotePropertyValue $Row.$Col
    }
    $Record
}
```

When that is done `$MyArray` will be an array of custom objects that you can work with all you'd like.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something simple.  Using your code exactly as written, when I type out $myArray, I see the sub-types.  But if I try to do a `$MyArray.servername = "dd"` it fails saying Property can not be found on the object.

Comment: That's because `$MyArray` is an array of objects. You could remove the `[array]` from the first line, or reference the object in the array by index `$MyArray[0].servername = "dd"`

Comment: Tested this, without the [array] reference, it is is exactly what I was trying to go.  Thank you..  You have 26k (at this moment), so the points may not mean much, but they are yours.  Even the values within the new object keep there types.  (string vs Boolean).  
Perfect, thank you..

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you have to unroll everything to go from a multidimensional array to a single dimension array. The path to go from a DataSet to a single row is:

```
DataSet -> DataTableCollection -> DataTable -> DataRowCollection -> DataRow
```

Which is:

```
$DataTableCollection = $DataSet.Tables   #Get the Tables
$DataTable = $DataTableCollection[0]     #Only need the first Table
$DataRowCollection = $DataTable.Rows     #Get the Rows
$DataRow = $DataRowCollection[0]         #Only need the first Row
```

Or, for a simplified one-liner:

```
$Row = $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]
```

This then allows you to access the properties as you are expecting.

```
$Row.ServerName = "asdf"
```

Comment: That lets him easily reference things, but his data is set to readonly, so he can't manipulate any values, which was the point of his post.

Comment: This explains how to access to retried data, but it still doesn't let me manipulate it.
If I tired `$DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].servername = "Test"` it still fails.

Comment: No. Don't use `$DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].servername` because, yes, the DataSet is read only. Assign the row to the `$Row` variable and use the DataRow as it is not read only.

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by TheMadTechnician is correct. Here is another, significantly faster way (if we are talking about thousands of rows) which only loops through column names once and stores the objects in an arraylist

First, get all the property names

```
[string[]]$Properties = @()
Foreach($col in $DataSet.Tables[0].Columns) {
    $Properties += $col;
}
```

Then, add all rows as a PSCustomObject (with column names from the dataset) to the arraylist:

```
$arrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Foreach($row in $DataSet.Tables[0]) {
    $arrayList.Add(($row | Select-Object $Properties)) > $null;
}
```